# Why is instanceof in TypeScript not working for inherited class?

Tags: typescript, instanceof

I've got the following class:

```
class ApiError extends Error {
    httpCode: number
    constructor(message:string, httpCode:number = 400) {
        super(message);
        this.httpCode = httpCode;
    }
}

export class ErrorForbidden extends ApiError {
    constructor(message:string = 'Forbidden') {
        super(message, 403);
    }
}
```

Then I create an instance like so:

```
const error = new ErrorForbidden();
console.info(error instanceof ErrorForbidden); // false
console.info(error instanceof Error); // true
```

So it seems it detects it's an instance of `Error` but not an instance of `ErrorForbidden` even though that's how I've created it.

Any idea why it's not working? And how to make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have your TypeScript set to compile to ES5 or some other pre-ES2015 version of JavaScript, TypeScript can't correctly subclass `Error` because it was impossible to do so prior to ES2015. So instead it produces something that's an `Error` but not an `ErrorForbidden` (in your case).

The generated JavaScript for your code (if I leave out `export` to make it easy in the Playground) looks like this if it's set to ES5 output:

```
"use strict";
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
        extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
            ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
            function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
        return extendStatics(d, b);
    };
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
var ApiError = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(ApiError, _super);
    function ApiError(message, httpCode) {
        if (httpCode === void 0) { httpCode = 400; }
        var _this = _super.call(this, message) || this;
        _this.httpCode = httpCode;
        return _this;
    }
    return ApiError;
}(Error));
var ErrorForbidden = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(ErrorForbidden, _super);
    function ErrorForbidden(message) {
        if (message === void 0) { message = 'Forbidden'; }
        return _super.call(this, message, 403) || this;
    }
    return ErrorForbidden;
}(ApiError));
var error = new ErrorForbidden();
console.info(error instanceof ErrorForbidden); // false
console.info(error instanceof Error); // true
```

...which shows `false`, `true`.

[Live on the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?target=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECCAOBLAogJ1Qe1dApgDwBccA7AExjU2wG8AoaB6ACwIPgGENScAuaYgK4BbAEY5U9RsAzEIBVAOAEsACiE4oYAOa85qRMS0AaZqw5deg0eOgBeaABYADE4CU0Ooy-QIA+OLUNCG0cVwBuSW9oAiZECAA6FjZObjtTZIsIrwBfWlzQSAp0LAAxLBFEUm5iXEIScjgkSiwPSOhpWXlFZVRAzR0ePQMtNIByMtQKqpJR908onz8A9X6cE2cAZnC23NzaDrlcYux7YhwAd2hm1Amp6pVtg4wQHHiDADMMFXEqaAM5MDEYA4DDvK7HW6VarhaAAelh0HeYBAEBw+xkEGerw+Xx+LX+BEBwNB4KoMPh0QUOCAA)

Compare with this when set to ES2015 output:

```
"use strict";
class ApiError extends Error {
    constructor(message, httpCode = 400) {
        super(message);
        this.httpCode = httpCode;
    }
}
class ErrorForbidden extends ApiError {
    constructor(message = 'Forbidden') {
        super(message, 403);
    }
}
const error = new ErrorForbidden();
console.info(error instanceof ErrorForbidden); // false
console.info(error instanceof Error); // true
```

...which shows `true`, `true`.

[Live on the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?target=2#code/MYGwhgzhAECCAOBLAogJ1Qe1dApgDwBccA7AExjU2wG8AoaB6ACwIPgGENScAuaYgK4BbAEY5U9RsAzEIBVAOAEsACiE4oYAOa85qRMS0AaZqw5deg0eOgBeaABYADE4CU0Ooy-QIA+OLUNCG0cVwBuSW9oAiZECAA6FjZObjtTZIsIrwBfWlzQSAp0LAAxLBFEUm5iXEIScjgkSiwPSOhpWXlFZVRAzR0ePQMtNIByMtQKqpJR908onz8A9X6cE2cAZnC23NzaDrlcYux7YhwAd2hm1Amp6pVtg4wQHHiDADMMFXEqaAM5MDEYA4DDvK7HW6VarhaAAelh0HeYBAEBw+xkEGerw+Xx+LX+BEBwNB4KoMPh0QUOCAA)